# How to write data on two children of one node simultaneously in fire base android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an android application through which Customers and Service Providers collaborate.  Firstly service provider send a visit request to customer specifying the potential visit time. After the customer accepts the visit request A timer starts which calculates how much time is left for visit of Service Provider.
If the time expires , then the 'visit request' should removed from 'Accepted/Pending Visit List' and added to  'Completed visits list' and a rating of '5' should be given automatically to both(i-e service provider and customer).   I have created two functions , one functions transfers the Visit Request from "Pending Visits List" to "Completed Visits List"  and the 2nd function calls inside the first function which gives rating of '5'to both users.
The problem is that When 2nd function runs, the first function could not complete its functionality because the 2nd functions runs before completion of the fires function. I am pasting spinet of code for both functions and their calling order and also a simpler version of  code at the end of post for easy understanding.

```
   // this functions Transfers Pending/Accepted Visit Request to Completed Visit Request.

public void transferPendingVisitToCompletedVisitListOfCustomerAndServiceProvider(final VisitRequest 
 visitRequest, final String customerUserName, final int position, final String 
  serviceProviderUserName){
    final DatabaseReference cus_ref = 
  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child("Customers");

    final Customer customer[] = new Customer[1];

    cus_ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ssn:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                customer[0] = ssn.getValue(Customer.class);
                if(customer[0].getUserName().equals(customerUserName)){
                    alCompletedVisitRequests = customer[0].getCompletedVisitsList();

                    if(alCompletedVisitRequests==null){
                        alCompletedVisitRequests = new ArrayList<>();
                        alCompletedVisitRequests.add(visitRequest);
                        customer[0].setCompletedVisitsList(alCompletedVisitRequests);
                        alPendingVisitRequests.remove(position);
                        customer[0].setPendingVisitsList(alPendingVisitRequests);

                         // updating the UI
                        PendingVisitRequestsAdapter pendingVisitRequestsAdapter = new 
                         PendingVisitRequestsAdapter();
                        listViewPendingVisits.setAdapter(pendingVisitRequestsAdapter);
                        cus_ref.child(customer[0].getId()).setValue(customer[0]);

                   //  Now Checking if the Visit Request is  is expired then rating of 5 should be 
                   // given to both users.
                        if(isPendingVisitExpired==true){


            // now handling the responseTime Rating of Service Provider and Customer
                             automaticallyAddResponseRatingOfServiceProviderandCustomer
             (MainActivity.mcustomer.getUserName(),serviceProviderUserName);
                        }

                    }

                    else{  //i-e alCompletedVisitRequests!=null

                        alCompletedVisitRequests.add(visitRequest);
                        customer[0].setCompletedVisitsList(alCompletedVisitRequests);
                        alPendingVisitRequests.remove(position);
                        customer[0].setPendingVisitsList(alPendingVisitRequests);

                          // updating the UI
                        PendingVisitRequestsAdapter pendingVisitRequestsAdapter = new 
                        PendingVisitRequestsAdapter();
                        listViewPendingVisits.setAdapter(pendingVisitRequestsAdapter);
                        cus_ref.child(customer[0].getId()).setValue(customer[0]);

                   // adding Response Time Rating automatically.Definition of this function is below

              automaticallyAddResponseRatingOfServiceProviderandCustomer
             (MainActivity.mcustomer.getUserName(),serviceProviderUserName);
                    }

                    visitRequest.setUserName(MainActivity.mcustomer.getUserName());


      addPendingVisitToCompletedVisitInServiceProvider(visitRequest,serviceProviderUserName);



                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Now I am pasting the definition of Response Time Rating Function which has called inside the first function as you see above.

```
 private void automaticallyAddResponseRatingOfServiceProviderandCustomer(final String CustomerUserName, final String ServiceProviderUserName){

    DatabaseReference databaseReference = 
      FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child("ServiceProviders");
    final String[] ServiceProviderId = new String[1];
    final String[] ServiceProviderImageUrl = new String[1];
    final ServiceProvider[] serviceProvider = new ServiceProvider[1];

    databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for(DataSnapshot ssn:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                serviceProvider[0] = ssn.getValue(ServiceProvider.class);

                if(serviceProvider[0].getUserName().equals(ServiceProviderUserName)){

                    ServiceProviderId[0] = serviceProvider[0].getId();
                    ServiceProviderImageUrl[0] = serviceProvider[0].getProfilePicUrl();
                    ResponseTimeRating responseTimeRating = new 
                           ResponseTimeRating(MainActivity.mcustomer.getImageUrl(),
                            MainActivity.mcustomer.getUserName(),5);

                    ArrayList<ResponseTimeRating> responseTimeRatingArrayListOfServiceProvider = 
                       serviceProvider[0].getResponseTimeRatingList();

                    if(responseTimeRatingArrayListOfServiceProvider==null){
                        responseTimeRatingArrayListOfServiceProvider = new ArrayList<>();
                        responseTimeRatingArrayListOfServiceProvider.add(responseTimeRating);

   serviceProvider[0].setResponseTimeRatingList(responseTimeRatingArrayListOfServiceProvider);
                        int averageResponseTimeRatingOfServiceProvider = 0;
                        int sum = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < responseTimeRatingArrayListOfServiceProvider.size(); i++) 
    {
                            sum = sum + 
          responseTimeRatingArrayListOfServiceProvider.get(i).getResponseRating();
                        }

                        averageResponseTimeRatingOfServiceProvider = sum / 
                      responseTimeRatingArrayListOfServiceProvider.size();

            serviceProvider[0].setResponseRating(averageResponseTimeRatingOfServiceProvider);

     automaticallyAddResponseRatingOfCustomer(ServiceProviderImageUrl[0],ServiceProviderUserName);

                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                        responseTimeRatingArrayListOfServiceProvider.add(responseTimeRating);

      serviceProvider[0].setResponseTimeRatingList(responseTimeRatingArrayListOfServiceProvider);
                        int averageResponseTimeRatingOfServiceProvider = 0;
                        int sum = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < responseTimeRatingArrayListOfServiceProvider.size(); i++) {
                            sum = sum + 
      responseTimeRatingArrayListOfServiceProvider.get(i).getResponseRating();
                        }
                        averageResponseTimeRatingOfServiceProvider = sum / 
 responseTimeRatingArrayListOfServiceProvider.size();

     serviceProvider[0].setResponseRating(averageResponseTimeRatingOfServiceProvider);

   automaticallyAddResponseRatingOfCustomer(ServiceProviderImageUrl[0],ServiceProviderUserName);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            DatabaseReference newDatabaseReference = 
         FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").
        child("ServiceProviders").child(serviceProvider[0].getId()
            );
            newDatabaseReference.setValue(serviceProvider[0]);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Now I am pasting simpler version of code for both functions code for easy understanding.

```
// definition of first function which transfers Pending Visit  From 'Pending Visits List' to 
//  'Completed Visit List'

      transferPendingVisitToCompletedVisitListOfCustomerAndServiceProvider
     (visitRequest,MainActivity.mcustomer.getUserName(),position,ServiceProviderUserName){

       // logic for transferring  'Visit Request' From 'Pending Visit List' to 'Completed Visit List'

         bla bla bla bla 
         bla bla bla bla 

         // now calling the function which gives rating to both Users
            automaticallyAddResponseRatingOfServiceProviderandCustomer
            (MainActivity.mcustomer.getUserName(),serviceProviderUserName);

       }// end definition of first function
```

The problem is that when the second function is called inside the first function then functionality of first function (i-e Transferring 'visit Request' From 'Pending Visit List' to 'Completed Visit List') does not completes which means it does not transfers the 'Visit Request' but gives the Rating.

But if I remove the second function(i-e rating function) from inside of first function, then The functionality of first function runs flawlessly and it transfer the 'Visit Request'  to 'Completed Visits 
 List'.   How I can make it possible to run the both functions functionality flawlessly?

Comment: I tried to answer below. If that is not what you're looking for, please edit your question to significantly reduce the scope of the information and code. The less we have to learn about your app, the more likely it is that we can help you. Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write to multiple locations with a single operation, you can use a multi-location update.

Say that you have these two write:

```
cus_ref.child(customer[0].getId()).setValue(customer[0]);
DatabaseReference newDatabaseReference =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child("ServiceProviders").child(serviceProvider[0].getId());
newDatabaseReference.setValue(serviceProvider[0]);
```

They could be combines as:

```
Map<String,Object> updates = new HashMap<String,Object>();
updates.put("/path/to/cus_ref/"+customer[0].getId(), customer[0]);
updates.put("/Users/ServiceProviders/"+serviceProvider[0].getId(), serviceProvider[0]);

FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().updateChildValues(updates);
```

Comment: But I have a slightly different situation. I have one function through which I have to just write data because  I have that data. That can be done very easily as you told.   But in my second function  first,  I need to read a value from node , then make changes in that value and again write value to that node. Actually that value is an Array List. So When I run my second function, write procedure runs  before completion of read procedure which is wrong thing.

Comment: If you're asking how to update a node in the database based on the existing value of that node, you'll want to use a transaction for that. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions. Aside from that, I won't be able to help further until you [reproduce the problem in a minimal setting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as I commented. There's just too much going on in there right now, which likely is why you're having a hard time figuring it out yourself, but also makes it really hard for anyone else to help you.